# SQL column name is same as Its function name

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is some Data in the MySQL Workbench. Column name is Left , Right in one table .

```
 Select PersonNumber,Left,Right,PhotoNumbr from Person.
```

This query is showing is error.
How can I fetch these records ,One thing cannot change column name in table.

Comment: use `\`backticks\``

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape in square brackets the column names which are coincident with SQL Server functions:

```sql
SELECT PersonNumber, [Left], [Right], PhotoNumbr
FROM Person;
```

For future reference, do not name your columns using keyword or function names.

Comment: It is not working , it is returning LEFT  and RIGHT column as column value.

Comment: SELECT PersonNumber, [Left], [Right], PhotoNumbr
FROM Person;  , after this, Query is working fine

Comment: above mention answer is wrong .Please change it

Comment: yes ,Now it is correct Please close it.